# How to convert of decisions tree to rulers or vector in PHP

Tags: php

I've this:

```
windy = TRUE
| humidity = high : no 
| humidity = normal
| | outlook = sunny : yes 
| | outlook = overcast : yes 
| | outlook = rainy : no
windy = FALSE
| outlook = sunny : no  
| outlook = overcast : yes  
| outlook = rainy : yes
```

and I want this:

```
windy   humidity    outlook    play
--------------------------------------
true    higth       x           no
true    normal      sunny       yes
true    normal      overcast    yes
true    normal      rainy       no
false   x           sunny       no
false   x           overcast    yes
false   x           rainy       yes
```

I'm looking for a way to convert the weka results (tree of decisions) into rules or a vector form

regards

Comment: So what did you try? Where's your problem in the transformation process?

Comment: I can not transform, I have no idea how to do it